# Error for unity 2019 following a Brackeys tutorial

Tags: c#

I am following the Brackeys tutorial for 3d movement and camera, and I keep getting the error:

> The type or namespace name transform could not be found

I've tried changing it and I'm extremely new to coding so I don't really know what to do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    public transform playerBody;

    float  xRotation = 0f;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
         float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
         float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

         xRotation -= mouseY;
         xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

         transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    
         playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is called `Transform` with a capital T

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing a capital on transform.

`public Transform playerBody;`

Comment: This is better suited as a comment than a full answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead